# Как ограничить доступ к html-странице паролем?

Tags: php, javascript

Всем привет! Вопрос в следующем:

Допустим, есть html-страница, на которой одно единственное поле для ввода пароля. 
При успешном вводе пароля человека перекидывает на нужную страницу.

Пароль хранится не в базе, а в каком либо файле, или в коде этой же страницы.

Как организовать доступ по паролю, чтобы при неверном вводе пароля под инпутом
сразу же появлялся див с заданным текстом типа "Вы ошиблись".

Comment: А [Basic access][1] HTTP авторизация вам не подходит?

  [1]: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth

Comment: Хранить пароль в коде страницы - моветон и грубое нарушение правил безопасности.
Для хранения пароля используйте какую-нибудь хеш-функцию, например md5

Comment: @Johny, сколько бы раз вы там не хешировали-перехешировали ключевую строку, толку от этого больше не станет. Так или иначе эта строка будет частью того же AJAX запроса, который для сервера будет верным, а, следовательно, злоумышленник( или школьник ) сумеет его вытащить без всяких проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если очень просто:

```
<form id="auth">
    <input type="password" id="pass" autofocus /><br/>
    <div id="err" style="display: none; color: red;">Кривой пароль</div>
    <button>Войти</button>
</form>
<script>
auth.addEventListener('submit', function (evt){
    evt.preventDefault(); // отменяем действие по умолчанию

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('POST', '/ctrl.php', false); // отправляем синхронный запрос на сервер
    xhr.send('pass='+pass.value);

    if( xhr.responseText == 'invalid' ){ // проверяем ответ
        err.style.display = ''; // выводим ошибку
    } else {
        location.href = xhr.responseText; // переходим на страницу
    }
});
</script>
```

**ctrl.php:**

```
<?php
   $pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? trim($_POST['pass']) : '';
   if($pass == $secret){
       echo "/secret-page.html";
   }  else {
       echo "invalid";
   }
?>
```

Comment: Я бы мог сказать, что пример прекрасно работает, но если вы его не поняли, то и ладно.

Answer (score 0):

Самый лучший способ изменить расширение Вашего файла с .html на .php 
Так Вы по крайней мере сделаете код, который представлен снизу, компилируемым сервером. Это означает, что он не будет доступен другим пользователем. Они получат только конечный результат.

Инструкция:

1. Просто добавьте этот скрипт наверху Вашей страницы
2. Замените login и pass на нужные Вам значения
3. Пользуйтесь на здоровье :)

P.S. Это слабая защита, для больших проектов стоит найти другое решение

```
<?php

$valid_passwords = array ("login" => "pass");
$valid_users = array_keys($valid_passwords);

$user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$pass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

$validated = (in_array($user, $valid_users)) && ($pass == $valid_passwords[$user]);

if (!$validated) {
  header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
  header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
  die ("Not authorized");
}

// Тут мы пишем те
echo "<p>Здравствуйте $user.</p>";
echo "<p> Поздравляем, Вы успешно прошли авторизацию.</p>";

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Миллион способов. Хранить пароль в коде самой страницы - небезопасно, тк он будет передан на клиент и при желании его расшифруют на раз два. Предлагаю вам реализовать через AJAX, смысл в следующем:

- при нажатии кнопки, скажем, "вход" отправляется запрос на сервер
- если сервер не доступен или ответ от сервера "error" показать div
- если ответ от сервера "accept" тогда form.submit();

код может быть такой:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
            url: 'login-ajax.php',
            success: function(response){
                if (response == 'accept') {
                    $('#do').submit();
                } else {
                    $('div').fadeIn(400);
                }
            },
            error: function(response){
                    $('div').fadeIn(400);
            }
     });
});
```

Фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/CxrVg/

Ну а в PHP собственно что то подобное:

```
<?php

$pass = ''; if (isset($_POST['pass']) { $pass = $_POST['pass']; }

/.. обезопасить входящие данные  ../
/.. сверить с базой ../

if ( %ПАРОЛЬ СОВПАЛ% ) { die('accept'); } else { die('error'); }

?>
```

Comment: ВОт заминусовали :(

Comment: Бред. Штатными средствами( HTML|JS|AJAX ) защитить ничего не получится. Разве только "школьников" отсеять. Ну а тому, кому будет надо, он без проблем сумеет подделать запрос, изучив JS в браузере, и получить доступ..

Comment: Спасибо. Суть ясна. А в PHP-файле что? Я имел ввиду, что пароль в переменной на странице. Ну тут безопасность не требуется, так как люди, которые заходить на страничку будут, даже не знают слов PHP и HTML.

Comment: Да кто вам предлагает шифровать пароль в js? проверить без перезагрузки с помощью хелпера да засабмитить форму а там проверить.

Comment: А собственно, как редирект сделать?

Comment: Форма самитится это и будет редиректом.

Comment: @Олег Б, нет сабмита, который нельзя было бы не перехватить. Взять, к примеру, браузер хром, клавишу F12 и вкладку Network :)

Comment: да вы можете перехватить что угодно, но в PHP то проверяется пароль, хоть с фальшивой страницы отправляйте запросы - в PHP то проверите POST данные и сверите с пароль, гляньте код внимательнее...

Comment: если это использовать как препроверку(не полагаться на отосланные данные а перепроверять) то можно сделать md5sum() со случайной солью, т.е. передаем юзеру md5(password.rand()); на его стороне по вводу считаем, опасность в таком случае - брутфорс (можно попробовать искуственно увеличить количество попаданий брутфорса, но все равно снижает секурность).